# Хелперы ASP.NET RAZOR MVC5 для использования с using

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

В ASP.NET RAZOR MVC5 существует такой замечательный хелпер как

```
Html.BeginForm()
```

Он может записываться как

```
@Html.BeginForm()
...
@Html.EndForm()
```

Так и

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

Как создать пользовательский хелпер по такому принципу. Например мне нужен блок div, блок не голый, а в нём какие-то основные элементы, допустим пять ссылок. Мне этот блок нужно дублировать постоянно, помимо фиксированных пяти ссылок нужно внутрь пихать кучу других элементов, это может быть кнопка/таблица/картинка/и т.д. Так вот, как это можно реализовать с помощью таких же красивых фигурных скобочек, а не писать Html.MyPerfectDivStart() и Html.MyPerfectDivEnd()

Есть вариант использовать MvcHtmlString и передавать в качестве параметра `List<MvcHtmlString>` из разных других компонентов, созданных мною. Но это некрасиво смотрится!

Comment: Создайте свой helper, один из методов вписываете в `@using`, а закрывающий -- в Dispose. Вы же знаете, что using -- это синтаксический сахар?

Comment: Тогда ведь метод должен создаваться как отдельный не статический класс?
Иначе как Dispose задать методу?

Comment: А, ну да. Посмотрите на класс System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm там очевидно.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

С формами вам не получится написать

```
@Html.BeginForm()
...
@Html.EndForm()
```

Потому что майкрософт в EndForm возвращает `void`, а не `MvcHtmlString`, и вы получите ошибку:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

И нельзя иметь две перегрузки `BeginForm`, одна из которых возвращает строку (для вызова без using), а вторая - `new MvcDiv` (нужно для разворачивания в using'е).

Как сделать хелпер, аналогичный `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm` для вызова через `using`.

Во-первых, сами `extension` для открытия/закрытия:

```
public static class MyDivHelper
{
    public static MvcDiv BeginDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div style='asdf'>");
        return new MvcDiv(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }

    internal static void EndDiv(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        viewContext.Writer.Write("</div>");
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, `disposing` для закрывающего `div`'а:

```
public class MvcDiv : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;

    public MvcDiv(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        if (viewContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewContext));

        this._viewContext = viewContext;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        MyDivHelper.EndDiv(this._viewContext);
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
@using (Html.BeginDiv())
{

}
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо!

Comment: 1. Зачем вызывать `GC.SuppressFinalize`, если финализатора всё равно нет? 2. Зачем реализовывать паттерн Dispose bool, если неуправляемых ресурсов нет и никогда не будет? Заметь, флаг даже не проверяется. Да и сама бизнес-логика с финализатором несовместима.

Comment: Поддержу Qwertiy - Dispose надо упростить. Это ж на самом деле не очистка ресурсов, а просто сахарок для вызова EndDiv.

Comment: Кроме того, имеет смысл сделать MvcDiv структурой (по принципу "нам это ничего не стоит, а одной аллокацией будет меньше")

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за комментарий. Это были остатки копипасты, убрал лишнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Структуры -- микрооптимизация, оставил в ответе класс, а кому нужно -- прочитает в комментариях.

Comment: @PavelMayorov аллокация на стеке возможна только если объект живет в рамках контекста, где он создан. Если уходит во вне - такой номер не пройдет. В данном случае мы возвращаем значение, да еще и создаем с помощью конструктора. Таким образом, будет даже не `initobj`, а именно `newobj` даже если сделать структуру. Т.е. выгоды никакой. Прежде чем заниматься микрооптимизацией надо разобраться, как все работает, и нужно ли вообще оптимизировать в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: @lorond `newobj` еще не означает, что объект будет создан в куче, это просто вызов конструктора и ничего больше

Comment: @PavelMayorov Память может быть выделена либо на стеке, либо в куче. На стеке - бесплатная аллокация - возможно, но при возврате из метода автоматически происходит такое же бесплатное уничтожение. Нам надо сохранить значение, значит выделять на стеке мы не можем. Остается только куча. Кстати, выделение памяти в нулевом поколении так же оооочень легкая операция (рекомендую посмотреть исходники clr). Ну и в довесок: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types/

Comment: @lorond аргумент на стеке все равно будет еще легковеснее

Comment: @PavelMayorov только если аллокация на стеке возможна. В данном случае аллокации на стеке не будет.

Comment: @lorond жду пруфов

Comment: @lorond почему-то C++ и Delphi запросто выделяют память под возвращаемые структуры на стеке - а для C# это, видите ли, невозможно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov рекомендую внимательно перечитать мои сообщения. Помимо того, что там все расжеванно, там есть еще и ссылка на статью Эрика Липперта. Если и этого не достаточно - исходники clr и windbg вам в помощь.

Comment: @lorond по приведенной вами ссылке нет информации о том, что нельзя вернуть структуру, выделив ей память на стеке. Рекомендую читать внимательнее.

Comment: @PavelMayorov подозреваю, вы не вполне понимаете, как работает аллокация на стеке.

Comment: @lorond подозреваю, вы никогда не декомпилировали программы...

Comment: ...и не читали соглашений о вызовах.