# Не отправляется запрос при использовании другого типа кнопки

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста почему если использовать `Ajax.BeginForm`, тогда нужно использовать кнопку с типом submit для отправки формы, а если использовать с помощью jquery `$.ajax` тогда можно просто button и форма всё равно отправиться. В чём разница?
Код с хелпером:

```
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookSearch", new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "results"
    }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
    }
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Код с jquery:

```
<div>
    <input id="txt" type="text" name="name" />
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Поиск" />
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/BookSearch",
                data: { "name": $('#txt').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status + 'Ошибка');
                },

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Вот так работают оба варианта, но если я в первом случае так же сделаю type у инпута, button, тогда запрос не отработает. Почему?

Comment: Рекомендую привести в вопросе код обоих примеров чтобы избежать неоднозначностей.

Comment: @AK, ну что сможете что то подсказать?

Comment: @AK вы вроде бы просили пример кода, а ответов не каких не предлагаете?

Comment: А я не только для себя просил, я просил для того, чтобы как можно больше людей могли ответить на ваш вопрос, а без конкретного образца это сделать сложнее, да и могли просто вопрос закрыть или заминусовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте сначала отвлечёмся от ajax и обратимся к обычным html-формам. Если на веб-странице будет расположена веб-форма (`<form></form>`), то все стандарты на html говорят о том, что отправка формы [происходит](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#submit-button) по нажатии на кнопку с type=submit, которых может быть более одной. В более новых стандартах кстати [упоминается](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#sec-forms), что не только кнопки могут быть submittable elements формы.

Я не видел браузеров, которые бы отклонялись от стандартов в этом плане, всё очевидно: кликнул по кнопке submit — пошла отправка формы, всё остальное не вызывает отправку формы.

Формы в asp.net mvc вы можете вставить либо вручную (`<form method="...`) создав разметку, либо использовав helper для формы @Html.Form — который точно так же вставляет те же самые `<form ...`.

Вот исходный код для этого хелпера:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  ...
  return htmlHelper.FormHelper(url, method, htmlAttributes);
}

private static MvcForm FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
  TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
  tagBuilder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
  tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
  tagBuilder.MergeAttribute(nameof (method), HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);
  bool flag = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;
  if (flag)
    tagBuilder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormIdGenerator());
  htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
  MvcForm mvcForm = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
  if (!flag)
    return mvcForm;
  htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
  return mvcForm;
}

internal static void EndForm(ViewContext viewContext)
{
  viewContext.Writer.Write("</form>");
  viewContext.OutputClientValidation();
  viewContext.FormContext = (FormContext) null;
}
```

То есть никакой особой магии когда вы пишете `@using(Html.BeginForm(...` нет. Я как-то отвечал на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684468/213987), можно ли сделать подобный хелпер самостоятельно — и в принципе, вы сами можете потренироваться в создании кастомных хелперов.

Давайте теперь вернёмся к ajax. Вы в коде пишете `@using(Ajax.BeginForm(...` — и эта конструкция вызывает аналогичный код, который вписывает `<form method="...`, никаких изменений.

Важно:

> Давайте определимся: отправка формы срабатывает только в случае
>   нажатия на submittable  элементы!

И неважно, ajax у вас или нет.

Но видите ли, никто не запретит вам на *любом* элементе формы сделать вызов *любой* javascript-функции. Можно сделать `alert()` или `console.log()`, раскрасить элементы или вызвать эфффект fade. Или — вызывать `this.form.submit()` Ну и даже (sic!) — сделать запрос к другому серверу. Собственно второй пример у вас именно такой: вы могли хоть onMouseOver или onKeyUp повесить вызов некоторого ajax-запроса, но навесили на событие onClick, которое вам кажется, что это событие onSubmit (для кнопок type=submit это действительно так!). Ну а что форма не отправится - ну так и не надо, действия оказываются выполненными практически одинаково.

Чисто гипотетически, я могу предположить, когда это может выстрелить, но такой случай вам в реальной практике не понадобится и так в ногу себе вряд ли получится выстрелить.

Никто не мешает вам сделать две кнопки:

- кнопка submit будет отправлять запрос на какой-то контроллер, который будет парсить данные считая что запрос приходит application/x-www-form-urlencoded (именно так отправляются в большинстве случаев формы)
- кнопка type=button будет отправлять запрос на какой-то другой экшн и в POST-запросе данные будут в json (тип application/json)

Вот [тут мы разбирали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/922057/213987) как раз очень похожий случай, когда было написано не:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
```

А было что-то типа (там использовалась библиотека axios, я для наглядности привожу эквивалент):

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

И напоследок пара слов не о том, что вы спрашивали. Есть одна очень частая ошибка связанная с написанием ajax, вы её допустили во втором примере.

С учётом того, что "и так всё работает" и "форму отправлять не надо" некоторые вебмастера пишут невалидный код. По html стандарту полагается что элементы типа input и button могут находиться только внутри формы. А где она у вас? Нету вообще.

Правильно вот так:

```
<div>
    <form ...>
        <input id="txt" type="text" name="name" />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="Поиск" />
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Насчёт того, что "ненуачо, работает же". Я не буду говорить о том, вёрстка должна быть валидной — это на совести каждого конкретного специалиста, я буду говорить о том, что зачастую люди ходят на сайты с отключенным javascript. И хотя вряд ли у человека с отключенным js будет полноценная возможность работать с сайтом, но в случае если у вас есть валидная форма с кнопкой submit — у человека остаётся шанс заполнить форму и отправить. А в случае, когда у вас input'ы и submit'ы висят в воздухе — никакого. Подумайте об этом.

Comment: AK спасибо за ответ, немного вас не понял по поводу что у меня во втором примере нет кнопки. Там же на пример есть кнопка? Или я что то не так понимаю? `<input id="btn" type="button" value="Поиск" />`

Comment: @Андрей Я вроде нигде не говорил, что "нет кнопки" (если покажете, где вы это увидели - я поправлю), я говорил "кнопка должна находиться внутри form и у вас нет form во втором примере". Дописал в ответ как должно быть.

Answer (score -1):

**Form** для получения данных через перезагрузку страницы

**Ajax Post** для динимаческой отрисовки.

Этот вопрос был [решён](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293375/ajax-vs-form-submission) ранее

Comment: Марат Зимнуров, вообще то через form страница тоже не перезагружается, аякс предусматривает как раз таки подтягивание данных без перезагрузки страницы если что.

Comment: @Андрей Ваш минус необоснован. Вам был дан ответ на различие в подходах и прикреплена ссылка, по которой можно было найти полное объяснение, либо минус Вам за некорректный вопрос.

Comment: Марат Зимнуров, я то в своём вопросе всё корректно объяснил. Я говорю о ajax запросах в обоих случаях. А по ссылке в одном случае говориться о ajax запросе, а во втором об обычной отправке формы post запросом без ajax. А у меня, если вы читать не умеете, в обоих случаях используется ajax, только в пером случае с помощью хелпера, а во втором с помощью jquery. Учитесь внимательно читать вопросы и приведённый код.