# Не определено беспараметрических конструкторов

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Имеется метод Init в параметрах есть класс стороннего разработчика UserInfo **который не содержит пустого конструктора**, но мне необходимо в определенных ситуациях обратиться к нему c пустыми паметрами, собственно при попытки сделать это вылетает ошибка, как обратить к методу без ошибки но с классом UserInfo

> Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов. Object type 'Nemiro.OAuth.UserInfo

```
public async string Init (RegisterViewModel model, UserInfo userData = default(UserInfo), bool External = false)
```

**Обращение к классу**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Init", "TestControl", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Comment: Покажите как вы вызываете метод Init. Ну и раз разработчик не предоставил конструктора по умолчанию, значит этот объект нельзя создать без параметров и вы обязаны предоставить все обязательные параметры, другого варианта нету. А default для класса вернёт null, а не какой-нибудь пустой объект. Да и вообще это фича времени компиляции.

Comment: Я бы аккуратно подходил к вопросу, т.к. похоже что сторонний автор применяет хорошую практику контроля входных параметров/инвариантов, проверяет логику. Возможно, стоит задекорировать класс, написав обёртку? [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684468/213987) я писал на тему создания своего хелпера формы.

Answer (score 0):

Если [это](https://github.com/alekseynemiro/nemiro.oauth.dll/blob/master/src/Nemiro.OAuth/UserInfo.cs) тот класс, то достаточно передать null в оба параметра конструктора.
К примеру так:

```
public async string Init (RegisterViewModel model, UserInfo userData = null, bool External = false)
{
     userData = userData ?? new UserInfo(null,null);
     //other logic
}
```

Comment: Нет подобное я уже пробовал, вылетает с той же ошибкой

Comment: @Сергей с той же ошибкой вылетать не может, просто по определению, скорее всего вылетает оно теперь у Вас с ArgumentNullException, это абсолютно логично, потому что, если автор класса добавил в конструктор два обязательных параметра, то они, прошу прощения за тафтологию, обязательны.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov, если посмотреть приведенные мной исходники, то как раз не обязательны. В конструкторе первой строкой идет
`if(mapping == null || !source.HasValue) { return; }`

Comment: Можно попробовать создать пустой конструктор в дочернем классе и через  `base` вызвать и определить параметры для родительского конструктора.